# "URL is on Google" - but I can't see it in the results

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

Google search console says "URL is on Google", but when I google for the URL, there are no results. what does this mean?

Comment: What is the search term you are using?

Comment: Have you tried the site command in your browser?  I.e. site:example.com  You should look at these previously answered questions:  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=no+results+in+google

Comment: yes tried both.

either  `example.com/page`  `www.example.com/page`  `site:example.com/page` ,  `https://www.example.com/page` and nothing. the domain itself is indexed long ago, but "page" is a section I've added about 5 days ago to my website.

Comment: Have you also searched for a unique sentence from the page in quotes?

Comment: just did, still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If the page is only 5 days old it's probably a little early to be alarmed.

Start with seeing what Google returns in GSC via "View Crawled Page".  Then on the right hand side of GSC, look at the HTML, Screenshot and More Info tabs.  If your page looks fine there, then you probably just need to be patient.

It can take a few weeks for content to show up, especially if you don't add new content very often.  IMO, "URL is on Google" means, "We know about the page. We'll put in our queue to actually have our bot index your content based on our own algorithms."  If you post content rarely (like every few months), Google will likely index your content more slowly, than if you post weekly or monthly.

Additionally, if you link to your new content from existing pages, Google is more likely to index it faster.

Finally, GSC has been undergoing changes in many areas over the past few months.  There recently were several weeks where you couldn't request indexing of pages via GSC.  It's possible that they may still be delaying indexing content that is only known about by our manual submission of URLs in GSC as part of these changes.